# Can spirit use a Factory instead of ADAPT_STRUCT to process rule?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-fusion

I'd like to use a factory function in a semantic action, but I haven't been able to find the right recipe using phoenix or fusion.

My spirit-qi rule that would look something like:

```
object = type_identifier >> arg_list;
```

and I'd like to have Fusion perform something like:

```
object = Factory(type_identifier)(arg_list)
```

instead of using `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` to create a structure containing `type_identifier` and `arg_list`.

How can something like this be done? Thanks.

Comment: If you provide a small sample we can help answer the question in more concrete fashion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In principle there are three approaches:

1. rely on the public constructor
2. use a semantic action (e.g. `qi::int_ [ qi::_val = boost::phoenix::construct<type_identifier>(qi::_1) ]`)
3. use attribute transformation traits [See [Customization of Spirit's Attribute Handling](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/advanced/customize.html) in the docs). In this case you'd simply have

   ```
    qi::rule<It, Mytype()> r = qi::_int;
   ```

   and the corresponding trait (`assign_to_attribute_from_value<MyType, imt>`) handles the assignment

Comment: The transformation_attribute trait was exactly what I needed. The [parse_date](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/parse_date.cpp) example was very helpful -- but I didn't know what to grep for. Thanks a bunch!